# Finding the residue, $z=n\pi$, and $e^{n\pi}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I have reached the following point in a residue calculation and am now unsure what to do:

$$Res_{z= n\pi}=\lim_{z\to n\pi}\{(z-n\pi)\frac{ e^z}{\sin(z) } \}$$

$$=\lim_{z\to n\pi}{\{\frac{e^z(z-n\pi)+e^z}{\cos(z)}\}}\tag{By LHopital}$$

Im now uncertain as to how to deal with $e^{n\pi}$, I have looked at the exponential form of a complex number, $e^{z}=e^{x+iy}$ but am not sure what to do when we have $n\pi$ instead of $x+iy$. Is there any identity I can use for when we have  $e^{n\pi}$?

Comment: $e^{n\pi}$ is a real number so you can simply leave your answer in that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As presented in the proposal and completion of steps:
\begin{align}
Res_{z= n\pi} &= \lim_{z\to n\pi} \left\{ (z-n\pi) \frac{ e^z}{\sin(z) } \right\} \\
&= \lim_{z\to n\pi} \left\{ \frac{e^z(z-n\pi)+e^z}{\cos(z)} \right\} \\
&= \frac{e^{n\pi} (n\pi - n \pi) + e^{n \pi}}{\cos(n \pi)} \\
&= (-1)^{n} \, e^{n \pi}
\end{align}